How can I insert an element after 2nd search result?
I am using JS to show two DIVs when a other DIV is visible on page (after a search).
Example of search results:
#div6
#div5
#div4
#div3
 --insert div
#div2
#div1

On bigger search results, it still adds after #div3.
#div8
#div7
#div6
#div5
#div4
#div3
 --insert div
#div2
#div1

Right now I am using this JS that is doing the job perfect whenever Div5 is visible.
function addDivs() {
    function isVisible(element) {
        return element.offsetParent !== null;
    }

// check visibility and insert
const div5 = document.getElementById("outcome5");
const div3 = document.getElementById("outcome3");

if (div5 && isVisible(div5)) {
    const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.className = "bbbbb";
    newDiv.textContent = "abc"; 
    div3.insertAdjacentElement("afterend", newDiv);
}

if (div5 && isVisible(div5)) {
    const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.className = "ccccc";
    newDiv.textContent = "xyz"; 
    div3.insertAdjacentElement("afterend", newDiv);
}

}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
   addDivs();
});

My problem is that if the search results get long, the DIV moves to the bottom.
My goal is to add the extra two div's after the 2th result, no matter how long the search outcome. (and not showing when no results).
I can create a lot of "check visibility and insert" but I am sure there has to be a easier way. Any help would be appreciated much.

It seems like it might be more straightforward to find the 2nd div (with document.querySelector()) and then use after() to insert the new div. All the options for insertAdjacentElement() tend to confuse me.

Instead of selecting the div by its ID, select it using querySelector.
Assuming the div that contains the search results has the id "outcome-container" you could edit your code like this:
function addDivs() {
    function isVisible(element) {
        return element.offsetParent !== null;
    }

    // check visibility and insert
   const targetDiv = document.querySelector("#outcome-container > div:nth-child(3)")

   if( !targetDiv ) {
       // there are less than 3 results
       return
   }

    const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.className = "ccccc";
    newDiv.textContent = "xyz"; 
    targetDiv.insertAdjacentElement("afterend", newDiv);
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
   addDivs();
});

This script checks if a 3rd result exists, if so, adds the new div after it.
If you want to show the div anyway, you can simply append it to the parent element instead of returning from the function
